# Can not save changes to properties.settings

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config, properties.settings

I'm trying to use properties.settings for the first time in a **C# WPF** project.

I have this code:

```
Settings.Default.comPort = "";
Settings.Default.baudRate = 9600;
Settings.Default.startUp = false;
Settings.Default.taskBar = true;
Settings.Default.desktopNotif = false;
Settings.Default.reset = false;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

But it didn't work and the settings wasn't saved. So I added this line

```
Console.WriteLine("test");
```

after that part, to check if it goes through the code, and it executed fine.
So It seems that it just jumps over those lines without execution or even throwing any exceptions.

Comment: How do you know they are not saved? [Which file are you looking at](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33237394/69809)? Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/469742/69809) answer your question?

Comment: Where did you check for the changes? `Default` means *default*, they are the *initial* values stored in your config file, *not* those saved in the user's config file. Or you tried to change application-scoped properties which aren't saved

Comment: I used two ways to test if they are saved. first, I commented out these lines and tried to read the value, but it was null. and second, I checked the app.config file and it contains the fields but the values were null

Comment: @Amir that didn't test anything. If you are trying to change application values, nothing will be saved anyway. User-scoped values are stored in the user's AppData\AppName folder

Comment: Did you check the AppData folder then ? Don't assume there is a bug in such basic functionality. People would have noticed long ago. You need to isolate what is actually happening. For example, if you are debugging the application, the settings may get cleared each time a change is detected. If you add/remove/change a setting, you need to call `Upgrade` to read the *old* settings. Otherwise your code would crash trying to read older, incompatible values

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos So you mean it might be because I run my code in the debug mode?

Comment: @Amir not exactly - different builds may result in different assembly numbers if you've used `*` as the minor version. Different assembly numbers use a different `appdata` folder to avoid mixing data from different versions. You'd have to check and upgrade settings anyway, as shown [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534261/how-do-you-keep-user-config-settings-across-different-assembly-versions-in-net/534335#534335): if  `UpgradeRequired` is true, call `Upgrade`, set the flag to `false` and save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [**Panagiotis Kanavos**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) I eventually found the problem. The code was correct, but when the program runs inside the visual studio, every time the settings are being overwritten. After building, I ran the `.exe file` in the `bin/release` folder and it worked just fine.